# How to concatenate query string

Tags: mysql, string, escaping

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE `id`=1 AND ";
    if(somecondition){
       $query .=" AND `ROUND(DATEDIFF(w.time_start, w.time_end) / 365.25)` >='".$data."'";
    }
```

What i expect is:When i use ' ' instead, it concatenates.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE `id`=1 AND `ROUND(DATEDIFF(w.time_start,w.time_end) / 365.25)`>='$data';
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Have a care to format you question a bit. You get the preview so you can see how it looks, and there are buttons you can use (e.g. use the `{}` button for code)

Comment: You are sure that the condition in your `if` statement returns true?

Comment: regarding your question: please add what you expect, what happens, etc. this is just dumping some code and saying it doesn't work. What would you even expect? there doesn't seem to be valid sql there, e.g. your backticks should be a `'` there I think? But also, if it would concatenate, it would say `SELECT * Table AND .....` that's not valid

Comment: yeah i am checking it while the condition returns true.@Jens

Comment: Found out what's wrong exactly.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having space at the begining was causing the problem and for mysql ' have to be used around values and ` backticks should be used around identifier name such as column name.